# Change tooltip value with Default Browser Tooltip option in Ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am following the ag-grid [document to create the defult browser tooltip](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-tooltip/#default-browser-tooltip) in my angular application.

Find below the code snippet that I have used,

```
//HTML

<ag-grid-angular
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [enableBrowserTooltips]="true"
  [tooltipShowDelay]="0"
>
</ag-grid-angular>

//class
columnDefs={
      field: 'created_at',
      headerName: 'Time',
      filter: false,
      valueFormatter: (params: ValueFormatterParams) =>
        this.sharedService.getRelativeDate(params.data.created_at),
      tooltipField: 'created_at',
      tooltipValueGetter: (params: ITooltipParams) => 'Custom value to be a tooltip',
}
```

**Issue**

The tooltip isn't rendering the value that is returning from the tootipValueGetter function

Answer (score 0):

The `tooltipField` property should be removed from the column def, so you only keep the `tooltipValueGetter`

```
columnDefs = {
      field: 'created_at',
      headerName: 'Time',
      filter: false,
      valueFormatter: (params: ValueFormatterParams) =>
        this.sharedService.getRelativeDate(params.data.created_at),
      tooltipValueGetter: (params: ITooltipParams) => 'Custom value to be a tooltip',
}
```